# Outlook 2013: "Messaging interface returned an unknown error. Cannot resolve recipient."

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am using Windows 8 with Outlook 2013.  I have one Exchange (Office 365) account and one Google Apps account using the Google Apps Sync software.

Occasionally, when replying to an e-mail or writing a new e-mail, I'll get an error reading "Messaging interface returned an unknown error.  Cannot resolve recipient."  It doesn't matter which account I try to send it from.  However, the common thread does seem to be that it only happens with recipients not in my address book.  Adding a recipient to my address book does seem to resolve the issue.

Searching online, I found suggestions that this could be caused by a corrupt PST file and used a tool to correct my PST file.  This made no difference.

How can I resolve this?  Adding recipients to the address book or logging in through the Gmail Web interface are workarounds but not really satisfying solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i think i figured it out... I removed all of the BUSINESS FAX Numbers from the contact cards and the emails began sending as normal!  I think it is an issue when sending emails to a group of people that have fax numbers stored...

Comment: There are a few reasons I don't think this is my problem:

1. I don't have any contacts with a business fax.
2. This happens whether I am sending to one person or many.
3. The determining factor is whether each contact is in my address book at all.